# Truncate string in Liquid and remove last word

Tags: liquid

I'm using Liquid within a Jekyll-powered blog and currently trying to truncate various strings to a fixed size.

However, both built-in filters don't produce the output I'm trying to procude.

If I use [`truncate`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/truncate/), I'm able to cut the string after a given number of characters:

```
{{ "Ground control to Major Tom." | truncate: 24 }} -> Ground control to Maj…
```

On the other hand, [`truncatewords`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/truncatewords/) allows me to shorten a string after a given number of words.

```
{{ "Ground control to Major Tom." | truncatewords: 4 }} -> Ground control to Major…
```

**However, I want to truncate a string after `x` characters and then remove the last word in order to not have fragmented words left at the end of the string.**

In the above example, my desired output after truncating 24 characters would be: `Ground control to…`

I tried to play around with the filter `last`, but didn't manage to find a suitable solution.

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would just split the string by space, then sequentially append each word until the total length exceeds 24

```
{% assign string = "Ground control to Major Tom." | split: " " %}

{% assign shortstr = "" %}
{% for word in string %}
  {% assign tempstr = shortstr | append: word %}
  {% if tempstr.size <= 24 %}
    {% assign shorstr = tempstr | join: " " %}
  {% else %}
    {% break %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I haven't tested it but it should be close if not ok